# SQL Server Express - Table Replication

Tags: replication, sql-server-express

New to this so apologies if I make any faux par's.

I am trying to replicate tables from one instance of SQL Server Express 2008 to another over the web.  I am trying to send 1 table in one direction and another table in the opposite direction.

I came up with the following options but have run out of research options:-

**Peer to Peer replication** - Excluded as Express cannot be a publisher only a subscriber to receive the data

**Linked servers** - Cannot find anything that I can relate to my problem, especially on linking two instances of SQL Server Express

**Web Services** - Want to avoid unless there is no other choice

Any other options, or help on the ones above would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Use Sql server 2012 and all your problem will be resolved. http://www.bulksmsglobal.in/sqlserver2012

Comment: SQL Server 2012 is not SQL Express . The OP asked specifically SQL Express ..